# Is there a more efficient function for finding []byte similarities?

Tags: performance, go, byte

I am looking for an efficient way to find the prefix similarity between two byte slices. I am currently using this but am looking for a more efficient way if possible.

Thank you.

```
s1 -> [0 15 136 96 88 76 0 0 0 1] 
s2 -> [0 15 136 96 246 1 255 255 255 255]

output -> [0 15 136 96]
```

```golang
func bytesSimilar(s1 []byte, s2 []byte) []byte {
    for !bytes.Equal(s1,s2) {
        s1 = s1[:len(s1)-1]
        s2 = s2[:len(s2)-1]
    }
    return s1
}
```

Benchmarking code:

```
func BenchmarkBytePrefix200(b *testing.B) {
    s1 := []byte{0, 15, 136, 96, 88, 76, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    s2 := []byte{0, 15, 136, 96, 246, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255}
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bytePrefix(s1, s2)
    }
}
```

Results on an MBP:

```
BenchmarkBytePrefix200-8    48738078            29.5 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Comment: What else have you tried? How about just indexing instead of re-slicing?

Comment: Could you post the implementation of `bytePrefix` func? I see only the implementation of the  `bytesSimilar` func.

Comment: This is incorrect for arrays like [1, 2, 3] and [1, 7, 3].

Comment: Yes @Veedrac, it is only for identifying similarity prefixes from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `bytePrefix` is the same as `bytesSimilar` in your question:

```
func BytesSimilarNew(s1 []byte, s2 []byte) []byte {
    for i := 0; i < len(s1); i++ {
        if s1[i] ^ s2[i] > 0 {
            return s1[:i]
        }
    }
    return []byte{}
}
```

then the comparison:

```
BenchmarkBytePrefix200
BenchmarkBytePrefix200-8        28900861            36.5 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkByteSimilarNew200
BenchmarkByteSimilarNew200-8    237646268            5.06 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
```

Comment: Thanks @dmkvl, yes I just renamed it before posting and forgot to correct the name.

Comment: @eober, it happens, I thought so.

Comment: `a ^ b > 0` should not be faster than `a != b`, so just use `!=`.

Comment: @Veedrac, are you sure? Please give evidences.

Comment: `BenchmarkByteSimilarXor-8           209317736          5.24 ns/op
BenchmarkByteSimilarInequality-8    224361943          5.32 ns/op` @Veedrac, yes you're right

Comment: Note that if len(s1) > len(s2) and the first bytes in s1 match all the bytes in s2, you'll run past the end of s2. It may be a good idea to pick out the max length or swap a shorter slice into the first position (either suffices, and if you're guaranteed len(s1) <= len(s2) you're OK to start with).

Answer (score 2):

My opinion, from your code above, the following section is very expensive on I/O resource

```
s1 = s1[:len(s1)-1]
s2 = s2[:len(s2)-1]
```

We can actually just do a simple loop and exit early when different byte found. With this approach, we don't need much memory allocation process. It is more lines in code, but better performance.

Code is as below

```
func bytesSimilar2(s1 []byte, s2 []byte) []byte {
    l1 := len(s1)
    l2 := len(s2)
    least := l1
    if least > l2 {
        least = l2
    }
    count := 0
    for i := 0; i < least; i++ {
        if s1[i] == s2[i] {
            count++
            continue
        }
        break
    }
    if count == 0 {
        return []byte{}
    }
    return s1[:count]
}

func BenchmarkBytePrefix200v1(b *testing.B) {
    s1 := []byte{0, 15, 136, 96, 88, 76, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    s2 := []byte{0, 15, 136, 96, 246, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255}
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bytesSimilar1(s1, s2)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBytePrefix200v2(b *testing.B) {
    s1 := []byte{0, 15, 136, 96, 88, 76, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    s2 := []byte{0, 15, 136, 96, 246, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255}
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bytesSimilar2(s1, s2)
    }
}
```

The comparison result is per below, 38.7ns/op vs 7.40ns/op

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: git.kanosolution.net/kano/acl
BenchmarkBytePrefix200v1-8      27184414                38.7 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytePrefix200v2-8      161031307                7.40 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
```

Comment: Thanks Arief. I appreciate the help.